# How to find the next number after a specific number appears in an array

Tags: python, list, methods

Hi I'm taking a course for beginners about Python on Udemy and I'm stuck on a specific
Exercise.

Define a variable called num_after_6. This variable should contain the value of the first number in the list

that appears after the first instance of the number 6. There is a method you should use to figure out where the 6 first appears in the list, and there is another technique you should use to get the number in the position after this.

Is the full description.

```
num_after_6 = random_nums.index(6) 
random_nums[num_after_6+1]
```

is the my attempt, Finding the index of the first 6 and and than adding the index +1 to find the number

This part is the number generator to get the random numbers
where

```
 import random as ra
ra.seed(1)
random_nums = []
for i in range(1000):
    random_nums.append(ra.randint(1,10))
```

Comment: what is your question? Please format your code by adding ``` above and below your code.

Comment: Please also add the output you are getting and the output you are expecting. This makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Random numbers where...what?

Comment: `random_nums.index(6)` gives the _index of six_ in your `random_nums` list. You want `num_after_6` to contain the _number after six_, not the _index of six_. After you get the index, you add one to it to access the number you want, but you don't do anything with that number. You need to assign it to the variable `nums_after_6`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. Only, the exercise is to store the *number after the first `6`* in `num_after_6`, while your code prints that number and stores the *index of the first 6* in the variable.

You will need to use a second variable for the index, or do it all in a one-liner like

```
num_after_6 = random_nums[random_nums.index(6)+1]
```

But note this will fail if there are no `6` in the list, or the only `6` is at the last position.